# Sencha touch Selectfield picker not showing correct selection

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Store of the selectfield contains **same word with different case** like Ed & ed.When we select **ed**,In the picker it is showing **Ed**.

Code:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Select',

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        label: 'Choose one',
                                    displayField:'firstName',
                valueField:'firstName',
                        store:Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
                            fields: [
                {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
             ],
        data : [
            {firstName: "Ed"},
             {firstName: "ed"},                   
            {firstName: "Tommy"},
            {firstName: "Aaron"},
            {firstName: "Jamie"}
        ]
    })
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kgt) for the problem

Answer (score 1):

In Sencha, the `selectfield` is somethings whose `value` doesn't distinguish between the caps and small letter. So, it has provided `valuefield`. If you create your `store` like this below, you will get the expected result:

```
store: Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
                        fields: [{
                            name: 'firstName',
                            type: 'string'
                        }, {
                            name: 'value',
                            type: 'string'
                        }],
                        data: [{
                            firstName: "Ed",
                            value: 'edCaps'
                        }, {
                            firstName: "ed",
                            value: 'edSmall'
                        }, {
                            firstName: "Tommy",
                            value: 'tommy'
                        }, {
                            firstName: "Aaron",
                            value: 'aaron'
                        }, {
                            firstName: "Jamie",
                            value: 'jamie'
                        }]
                    })
```

Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/132o) also. Happy coding! :)